# Accordion requiring two clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

In [this website](http://89.151.89.43/acatalog/tradititional-radiator-valves-p1.html) if you look in the left and try collapse the Filters on the left hand side it requires two clicks for it to work, any ideas?

It is using jQuery UI CSS and works fine on [this page](http://89.151.89.43/acatalog/Trade-Essentials-2-Column-Radiator-H500-x-W622-TE2_500X622W.html#SID=102).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
$(".closed").accordion({
autoHeight: true,
collapsible: true,
icons: false,
active : true,
heightStyle : 'content'
});
});
```

Your accordion configuration is not correctly applied, as you can see inspecting, the aria-expanded attribute is set to false on your expanded tabs. A simple workaround to apply configuration could be calling refresh method on your class:

```
$(".closed").accordion("refresh")
```

Answer (score 1):

The initial setting for `<div id="FilterPropertyOptions_S_1_66413_0">` is wrong. The accordion should be closed but is open. On the first click, it will assign `display:block` (which is the initial state) and on the second click it will close the accordion. When the screen is displayed for the first time, the setting should be `display:none`.

Update: this is valid for the first accordion. Others may have another `id`. You also need to validate the chevron that's used linked to the display setting.

Comment: Hi Gerard,Let me to find the correct answer which was it not being correctly applied as by default it should be open, rather than closed.

Comment: I see your problem is solved :) Good luck with your project.